# Omit lines from the beginning or end of a file in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, head, tail

Given a text file `a.txt`, how to cut the head or tail from the file?

For example, remove the first 10 lines or the last 10 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to list all but the last 10 lines of a file:

```
head -n -10 file
```

to list all but the first 10 lines of a file:

```
tail -n +10 file
```

Answer (score 2):

To omit lines at the beginning of a file, you can just use `tail`. For example, given a file `a.txt`:

```
$ cat > a.txt
one
two
three
four
five
^D
```

...you can start at the third line, omitting the first two, by passing a number prepended with `+` for the `-n` argument:

```
$ tail -n +3 a.txt
three
four
five
```

(Or just `tail +3 a.txt` for short.)

To omit lines at the end of the file you can do the same with `head`, but only if you have the GNU coreutils version (the BSD version that ships with Mac OS X, for example, won't work). To omit the last two lines of the file, pass a negative number for the `-n` argument:

```
$ head -n -2 a.txt
one
two
three
```

If the GNU version of `head` isn't available on your system (and you're unable to install it) you'll have to resort to other methods, like those given by @ruifeng.

Answer (score 1):

to cut the the first 10 lines, you can use any one of these

```
awk 'NR>10' file
sed '1,10d' file
sed -n '11,$p' file
```

To cut the last 10 lines, you can use

```
tac file  | sed '1,10d' | tac
```

or use `head`

```
head -n -10 file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat a.txt | sed '1,10d' | sed -n -e :a -e '1, 10!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
```

Comment: You should not `cat` the file to `sed`, it can read the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\n';array=( $(cat file) )
for((i=0;i<=${#array[@]}-10;i++))  ; do echo "${array[i]}"; done
```

Comment: It isn't super clear what your code is doing. Perhaps you could break it up into more lines and explain how the answer applies to the question.